# linear dependency in a system

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given a vector system $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}$, how can I prove that $S$ is dependent iff $S'=\{v_1,...,v_i,...,v_j + mv_i,...,v_k\}$ is also dependent (with arbitrary $i,j \in\{1,...,k\}$ and $m$ a coefficient)?

Same question for $S''=\{v_1,...,v_{i-1},v_j,v_{i+1},...,v_{j-1},v_i,v_{j+1},...,v_k\}$
and  $S'''=\{v_1,...,v_{i-1},mv_i,v_{i+1},...,v_k\}$.

All I know is the linear relationship between vectors but I'm clueless on how to apply it in such a situation.
I would highly appreciate a detailed answer.

PS: Do all of these systems have the same rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use $S\sim S'$ to denote *$S$ is linearly independent iff $S'$ is linear independent*.

1. $S \sim S'$

   - $(\Rightarrow)$: Suppose $S$ is linearly independent.  $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{j-1} v_{j-1} + a_j (v_j + mv_i) + a_{j+1} v_{j+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$  Then add and subtract $ma_jv_i$ on the LHS.
     $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + (a_i+ma_j) v_i + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots + a_{j-1} v_{j-1} + a_j v_j + a_{j+1} v_{j+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$  Since $S$ is linearly independent, we have $a_n = 0$ for $k = 1,\dots,i-1,i+1,k$ and  $a_i+ma_j = a_i+m(0)=0$, so $a_n=0$ for all $n = 1,\dots,k$.
   - $(\Leftarrow)$:  Suppose $S'$ is linearly independent. $\sum_n a_n v_n = 0$.  Then add and subtract $ma_jv_i$ on the LHS.  $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + (a_i - ma_j) v_i + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots + a_{j-1} v_{j-1} + a_j (v_j + m v_i) + a_{j+1} v_{j+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$
     Since $S'$ is linearly independent, we have $a_n = 0$ for $k = 1,\dots,i-1,i+1,k$ and  $a_i - ma_j = a_i - m(0)=0$, so $a_n=0$ for all $n = 1,\dots,k$.
2. $S \sim S''$

   - $(\Rightarrow)$: Suppose $S$ is linearly independent.  To prove linear independence of $S''$, write $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + a_i v_j + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots + a_{j-1} v_{j-1} + a_j v_i + a_{j+1} v_{j+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$  Swap the terms $a_i v_j$ and $a_j v_i$ to get $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + a_j v_i + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots + a_{j-1} v_{j-1} + a_i v_j + a_{j+1} v_{j+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$  Use the linear independence of $S$ to finish this part.
   - $(\Leftarrow)$:  Suppose $S''$ is linearly independent. $\sum_n a_n v_n = 0$.    To prove linear i'ndependence of $S$, swap the terms $a_i v_j$ and $a_j v_i$ to get $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + a_i v_j + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots + a_{j-1} v_{j-1} + a_j v_i + a_{j+1} v_{j+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$  Use the linear independence of $S''$ to finish this part.
3. $S \sim S'''$

   - $(\Rightarrow)$:  Suppose $S$ is linearly independent.  To prove linear independence of $S'''$, write $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + a_i (mv_i) + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0.$$  To use linear independence of $S$, *we need $m\ne0$* so that the term $a_imv_i$ *won't* vanish.  We have $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + (a_im) v_i + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0,$$ so $S'''$ is linearly independent.
   - $(\Leftarrow)$:  Reverse the above process.  Suppose $S'''$ is linearly independent.  To prove linear independence of $S$, write $$ \sum_n a_n v_n = 0.$$  To use linear independence of $S'''$, *we need $m\ne0$* so that the coefficient $a_i/m$ is *defined*.  We have $$a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_{i-1} v_{i-1} + \frac{a_i}{m} mv_i + a_{i+1} v_{i+1} + \cdots a_k v_k = 0,$$ so $S$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Just another question. By proving that one system is linear independent iff the other one is also independent, suffices or is the same as proving dependency?

Comment: $P \iff Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \iff \neg Q$

Comment: Indeed, I just have to clear any uncertainties in my head. I do appreciate your response a lot.